# Can I publish map>-odom tf which can be used by amcl?

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish map>-odom tf which can be used by amcl or other localization packages. Is there a way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327174/can-i-publish-map%3E-odom-tf-which-can-be-used-by-amcl?/) by [sajal](https://answers.ros.org/users/41875/sajal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL publishes the map -> odom transform so if you're using AMCL do not publish any transform between those frames.

But to answer your direct question: YES you CAN publish that tf but it would not be useful unless your node is capable of localizing the robot in the map and publishing the correction via the TF.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sajal](https://answers.ros.org/users/41875/sajal/) on 2019-06-27**:
My amcl package is not publishing map>-odom tf thats why i was trying that. Are there any changes I need to make to use the amcl package provided by navigation stack?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-06-29**:
You need to figure out what us wrong with your configuration. Have gone through the nav stack tutorials?

**Comment by [Oysster](https://answers.ros.org/users/49521/oysster/) on 2020-08-09**:
Hey bro, I got the same error.My amcl doesn't publish the map-->odom tf. Have you sovler the problem?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-08-13**:
Oyster - That transform is the entire reason for AMCL. If it isn't publishing it, it means it is not receiving the input it expects. The log file likely has warnings from AMCL complaining about something. Use that info.